# wordpress german language issue

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to develop a German language word-press site. but the contents are shown like

```
Bewusst ern�hren.
```

How can I remove these symbols.

```
<html lang="de-DE" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">
<meta content="de-DE" name="language">
<meta content="de-DE" name="content-language">
```

I have added these codes but still the issue is there.

Comment: Check if your editor is saving the page in UTF-8 and not in some other encoding.

Comment: Seems to me like the font you are using does not include the characters you are trying to use. Have you tried using another font/theme?

Comment: @DennisJaamann i have tried other fonts but it is not working.

Comment: @DennisJaamann when I check using firebug...in the Net tab ...the Html section is correctly.

Comment: did you check your LOCALE in wp-config ?? and your DB encoding?

Comment: I'd suggest inspecting the `post_content` in the table `wp_post` directly in the database, just to confirm the data is being recorded without bugs.

Comment: contents with encoding problem are in the template or come from the WP editor?

Answer (score 0):

Install [UTF-8 Database Converter](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/utf-8-database-converter/) and let it fix your databases.